# Uploading multiple images - Only one successful Android Volley

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I am trying to upload multiple images from android using volley. In android I checked many times there is no error between sending encoded string in the script. But I noticed that when the script processes the strings, only the last one is uploaded successfully, the rest failed. The error goes to the String Request in android volley and I receive a volley error.

**UploadImages()**

```
static BaseUrl baseUrl;
    AddPropertyImagesCommand command = new AddPropertyImagesCommand(this);
    private void UploadImages(){
        for (String imagePath: imageList){
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(imagePath).requestSize(256,256).getBitmap();
                final String encodedString = ImageBase64.encode(bitmap);
                String imageName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
                intent = getIntent();
                final int property_id = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("property_id"));

                String ADD_IMAGE_REQUEST_URL = baseUrl.getBaseUrl() + "addPropertyImages.php";
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, ADD_IMAGE_REQUEST_URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "imagelist count: " + imageList.size());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while uploading image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Volley Error: " + error.toString());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("encoded_string", encodedString);
                        params.put("image_name", image_name);
                        params.put("property_id", property_id + "");
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                command.add(stringRequest);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        //execute the singleton class from volley which is addtorequestqueue
        command.execute();
    }
```

Then it goes to my php script:

**addPropertyImages.php**

```
<?php

    include "connection.php";

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;

    if(isset($_POST['property_id'])){
        $encoded_string = $_POST['encoded_string'];
        $image_name = $_POST['image_name'];
        $property_id = $_POST['property_id'];

        //method to upload images
        upload($encoded_string, $image_name, $property_id);
        exit;
    }else{
         echo "image not in";
         exit;
      }


    function upload($encoded_string, $img_name, $property_id){

        //create unique image file name based on micro time and date
         $date = date('Y:m:d H:i:s');
        $now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
        $id = $now->format('YmdHisu');

        $upload_folder = "listing_images";
        $image_path = "$upload_folder/$id_$img_name";
         $decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);

         if(file_put_contents($image_path, $decoded_string) != false){
            echo "upload success";
         }else{
            echo "upload failed";
         }

    }
?>
```

**Logcat:**

```
01-24 10:29:02.229 23401-23401/homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek D/AddPropertyImages: Image name: P_20170122_220217.jpg
01-24 10:29:02.229 23401-23401/homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek D/AddPropertyImages: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/P_20170122_220217.jpg
01-24 10:29:04.382 23401-23401/homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek D/AddPropertyImages: Image name: P_20170124_090947.jpg
01-24 10:29:04.382 23401-23401/homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek D/AddPropertyImages: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/P_20170124_090947.jpg
01-24 10:29:07.745 23401-23401/homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek D/AddPropertyImages: Image name: P_20170121_131658.jpg
01-24 10:29:07.745 23401-23401/homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek D/AddPropertyImages: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/P_20170121_131658.jpg
01-24 10:29:18.075 23401-23401/homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek D/AddPropertyImages: imagelist count: 3
01-24 10:29:26.888 23401-23401/homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek D/AddPropertyImages: Volley Error: com.android.volley.TimeoutError
01-24 10:29:27.329 23401-23401/homeseek.app.android.capstonehomeseek D/AddPropertyImages: imagelist count: 3
```

I am using Oum Saokosal's way of uploading image to server by android volley. 
Youtube page: https://www.youtube.com/user/oumsaokosal/featured

Comment: coz u r sending only one image `params.put("encoded_string", encodedString);`

Comment: i believe im using loop to get all the image.

Comment: But your hashmap is not taking any loop image, it's just taking last one.

Comment: can you show me what is your solution to my problem? it is in the inside loop, every request i put it in a class where it stores it into an arraylist and when its all finished it will be send all hashmap